# See the exact byte sequence of an R string?

Tags: r, unicode, string

How can I get the byte sequence of a particular UTF-8 string?  I'm seeing what looks like some bug in the regex engine which is only triggered in some edge cases, and I'd like to know exactly what data it's working on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe `charToRaw`?

```
> charToRaw("R-string")
[1] 52 2d 73 74 72 69 6e 67
```

Answer (score 3):

Also check out the hexView package by none other than Paul Murrell.

Comment: Neat, but that's more for viewing files rather than strings.